# MySQL- How to implement server-side password hashing

Tags: mysql, bcrypt, password-hash

I am creating a database and I need to store user passwords.  I am already using bcrypt to hash the passwords on the client side, but I have read that only hashing on the client side makes the hash essentially equivalent to a password as far as the database is concerned.  I'd like to hash the passwords (which are now hashes) again before they are stored in the database.  Do I have to use a method native to MySQL like `SHA2(pwd)`, or is there a way to use bcrypt on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Bcyrpt is a good call here, but you should be doing the hashing on the server end, not the client. The client can't know all the information it needs to produce a hash you can verify is correct, only the server has that information.

What you need to do is pass through the password securely, such as over HTTPS, and hash it there in your application layer. MySQL alone does not have the functions necessary to do proper password hashing. SHA2 is completely inadequate, it's a high-speed hash by design which makes it immediately unsuitable. Password hashing algorithms are deliberately slow to make brute-forcing passwords painfully expensive.

Comment: I'm hashing on the client because I read that it is good practice for protection from MITM attacks.  But my actual question is exactly what you're saying.  How do I implement bcrypt on the server side?  I'd like to avoid SHA2 if at all possible.

Comment: I don't know where you read that, or if you read it correctly. The only time I've seen client-side hashing is with challenge-response type systems, and most of those have died off because SSL/TLS has made it pointless, the channel itself can be secured. Hash *once*, properly, and you'll be fine. bcrypt, scrypt, or any other password-specific hashing algorithm, especially one with adjustable difficulty, is the key here.

Comment: MySQL cannot do bcrypt, at least not out of the box. It's typically the case you hash your passwords in some application layer. That could be Java, Python, Ruby, Node.js, PHP, it doesn't matter, virtually every one has a bcrypt implementation of some sort. MySQL, like many RDBMses is just a data store.